# How to set tab text center in my tablet layout?

Tags: android, android-layout, android-tabs

I am working on tablet layout largeland where i want to center the text but it appears in the corner how can i set in the center  [image]

xml is here

```
    <android.support.design.widget.TabLayout
    android:id="@+id/tabs"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="@color/tab_background_color"
    android:elevation="4dp"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    app:tabGravity="center"
    app:tabIndicatorColor="@color/tabIndicatorColor"
    app:tabIndicatorHeight="5dp"
    app:tabMode="fixed"
    app:tabSelectedTextColor="@color/tabSelectedTextColor"
    app:tabTextColor="@color/tabTextColor">       </android.support.design.widget.TabLayout>
```

Answer (score 11, accepted):

```
           android:layout_width="match_parent"
           android:layout_height="wrap_content"
           app:tabMaxWidth="0dp"
           app:tabGravity="fill"
           app:tabMode="fixed"
```

Comment: it's work for me but why app:TabMaxWidth="0dp" ?  what it means?